# change maven j2ee deploy name

Tags: deployment, netbeans, jakarta-ee, maven

I'm developing an app in maven and it's deploy name is concatenation of `artifactId + "_" + groupId + "_" + "packaging" + "_" + version` which is pretty ugly. And I'm lookuping for an EJB and I would need to change the uri after eventual version change.
Do you know how to change this deploy name?

I'm deploying it via netbeans.

Answer (score 2):

it's a netbeans bug and will be available in build *201102050000*.

[Netbeans bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195026)

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation about finalName which should do the trick.

Comment: do you mean finalName in build tag? I have that one set. I think it hos something to do with NetBeans because when I deploy it with admin console the deployName is OK.

Comment: Yes i mean the finalName in build tag. Did you try to do it on console?(mvn install / mvn deploy)

Comment: sorry for late response at first, Yes, I tried to deploy it without NetBeans, and the name is as in finalName. But I want it to be applied in NetBeans also. Is this possible?

Comment: Isn't it applied to NetBeans ? If not i'm a little bit suprised cause NetBeans calls Maven directly ...so it should be..? If not i don't understand that neither.